# What is the strongest public-key encryption method?

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm wondering what is the strongest algorithm for public/private key encryption.
It seems to me that PK encryption didn't keep up with symmetric algorithms when it comes to security. RSA is prevalent, but it looks dated, rather weak compared to AES and it might actually be compromised (thanks to the NSA)

What superior methods/algorithms/software are out there? Which is the strongest?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography

Comment: Depending on your preference you can either use RSA with larger keys (between 2048 and 4096 bits), which is a bit slow. Or ECC with keys between 255 and 521 bits. Personally I use a 255 bit elliptic curve called Curve25519.

Comment: Predictions are hard. For example if quantum computers become practical, RSA, finite field crypto, and elliptic curve crypto all become obsolete. But post-quantum schemes, like McElise or NTRU have their share of issues too, such as huge public keys (>100kB) or patents.

Comment: You may want to post this question to http://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, according to the literature on ECC, it would be more resistant to a "quantum computing" attack.

Comment: @mbratch From what I know it's broken. There is an analog of Shor's algorithm for ECC, so once a Shor able QC with a ~1000 bits can be built, all RSA, FFC, ECC break. ECC might be slightly weaker even since it's typically used with smaller keys (255-521) instead of (2048-4096). There are some post-quantum algorithms using elliptic curves, but those aren't normal ECC.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Interesting. I'll need to investigate that but I have not heard or read that ECC is "broken". Also, they key size itself doesn't make it weaker, at least not at those key sizes. My understanding is that the computational ability to reverse engineer the key, for other reasons than key size, is what makes RSA more breakable than ECC. But, thanks, you gave me some things to look into.

Comment: ECC is only broken when you have a large QuantumComputer, not on conventional computers, so I wouldn't call it "broken" outside a post-quantum context. One paper about adapting Shor's algorithm to QCs: http://arxiv.org/abs/quantph/0301141 "A 160 bit elliptic curve cryptographic key could be broken on a quantum computer using around 1000 qubits while factoring the security-wise equivalent 1024 bit RSA modulus would require about 2000 qubits"

Comment: Okay. So the consensus is that ECC is the strongest at present. (Until quantum computers)
I'm assuming that new methods will be have to be developed in the quantum computer age.

Answer (score 1):

ECC has a bit of a problem at the moment [Backdoor into ECC?](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2013/09/nsa-backdoor/)

Comment: The back door was found six years ago and it only becomes a scandal now... How sad is that?
The fact that the NSA/USA is corrupted is nothing new.
So I assume this means one needs to avoid any ECC implementation that has any connections to the NSA stuff.